# Picking selected options in a multiple select

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple DDL with items built dynamically with PHP and I want to store the selected options on page load, so as to be able to restore them later discarding the changes made.

So, after building the DDL:

```
var store = [];
ob = document.getElementById('getall_writers'); nr = ob.length;
for(var i=0; i < nr; i++) {
    if(ob.options[i].selected) { store[i] = i ;}
}
```

What is my mistake? It always has `store.length=2`.

Comment: I think your `nr` value is wrong. If you want the number of options in a `select` element, then you need to use `{selectelementreference}.options.length`.

Comment: @CBroe nope, it does not hurt, but `.length` is already the number of options, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested and modified it a little bit to store the value (not the id), but it looks good: http://jsfiddle.net/ts92oafp/1/

```
var store = [];
var ob = document.getElementById('getall_writers');
var nr = ob.length;
for(var i=0; i < nr; i++) {
    var option = ob.options[i];
    if(option.selected) {
        store.push(option.value);
    }
}
console.log(store);
```

Isn't this what you want?